# Embed Google Map with search bar

Tags: google-maps

I'd like to create a Google map with a search box to embed into my site. I've already created the custom map with my markers via my google maps account.

Unfortunately the html embedded maps don't include a search box within a map, so I believe I need the Google API. All I need a map with a search box and zoom (zoom seems there by default), so that I can add places of interest (clubs in my case) from my Google account. I would like visitors to be able to type a place of interest in the search box, and it will take them to that location on the map, and show local clubs nearby.

I've already spent some time looking for examples, so that I can modify it to suit my needs, but have not found something similar. My programming skills are quite limited, so I'm looking for a simple solution.

Can anyone point me in the right direction here please?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Places Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#places_autocomplete) along with [custom controls](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls#CustomControls).

Answer (score 1):

This might help another users for head start.
I have written a script that has two search boxes with Google place search auto completion and then It calculates the route and shows on the map.

Below is example link. (just download it and open in browser)

[Google Place Search & Calculate route between two locations](https://github.com/mjrulesamrat/google_maps/blob/master/google_directions_search_demo1.html)

Answer (score 0):

You may add a text box to your page and get content from the text box. This is independent from Google map.

Comment: Thank you! How would the content from the text box be used to take the visitor to the location on the map that they typed in though?

Comment: @Alex use geocoding service to get the (lat, lng) of the place that visitor enters. then show a marker or something there.

Answer (score 0):

See the JSFiddle attached here: [Embedded Google Map With Search Bar](https://jsfiddle.net/n8ao9r7h/) from [Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox).

> The below snippet **DOES NOT** work because it needs your Google API
> Key.

```js
// This example adds a search box to a map, using the Google Place Autocomplete
// feature. People can enter geographical searches. The search box will return a
// pick list containing a mix of places and predicted search terms.
// This example requires the Places library. Include the libraries=places
// parameter when you first load the API. For example:
// <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places">
function initAutocomplete() {
  const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: { lat: -33.8688, lng: 151.2195 },
    zoom: 13,
    mapTypeId: "roadmap"
  });
  // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
  const input = document.getElementById("pac-input");
  const searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);
  // Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.
  map.addListener("bounds_changed", () => {
    searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
  });
  let markers = [];
  // Listen for the event fired when the user selects a prediction and retrieve
  // more details for that place.
  searchBox.addListener("places_changed", () => {
    const places = searchBox.getPlaces();

    if (places.length == 0) {
      return;
    }
    // Clear out the old markers.
    markers.forEach(marker => {
      marker.setMap(null);
    });
    markers = [];
    // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
    const bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    places.forEach(place => {
      if (!place.geometry) {
        console.log("Returned place contains no geometry");
        return;
      }
      const icon = {
        url: place.icon,
        size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
      };
      // Create a marker for each place.
      markers.push(
        new google.maps.Marker({
          map,
          icon,
          title: place.name,
          position: place.geometry.location
        })
      );

      if (place.geometry.viewport) {
        // Only geocodes have viewport.
        bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
      } else {
        bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
      }
    });
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
  });
}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
#map {
  height: 100%;
}

/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#description {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

#infowindow-content .title {
  font-weight: bold;
}

#infowindow-content {
  display: none;
}

#map #infowindow-content {
  display: inline;
}

.pac-card {
  margin: 10px 10px 0 0;
  border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: Roboto;
}

#pac-container {
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  margin-right: 12px;
}

.pac-controls {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 11px;
}

.pac-controls label {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

#pac-input {
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-left: 12px;
  padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 400px;
}

#pac-input:focus {
  border-color: #4d90fe;
}

#title {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #4d90fe;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding: 6px 12px;
}

#target {
  width: 345px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Places Search Box</title>
    <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
    <script
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initAutocomplete&libraries=places&v=weekly"
      defer
    ></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style.css" />
    <script src="./app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input
      id="pac-input"
      class="controls"
      type="text"
      placeholder="Search Box"
    />
    <div id="map"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```