# Google Maps: How do you embed it WITH search bar?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

Hey I'm trying to integrate Google Maps into a website. Embedding Google Maps at a **certain** map location is quite easy, since you can generate the code for embedding on google maps itself through the share button, but this hides the search bar which I need for my game.

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d193595.15830869428!2d-74.119763973046!3d40.69766374874431!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x89c24fa5d33f083b%3A0xc80b8f06e177fe62!2sNew%20York%20City%2C%20New%20York%2C%20USA!5e0!3m2!1sde!2sde!4v1573800931555!5m2!1sde!2sde" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

Throughout the website players get coodrinates which you can enter into google maps to be shown the right location. **Though** what i would like to do is use the **default google maps** within an iframe for example so people can read and enter these coordinates without having to switch pages constantly.

Is there a way to do this, or do i have to pay for that? I'm currently looking into alternative map providers.

Comment: What does your code look like? Are you using the Google maps JavaScript API?

Comment: @geocodezip i was actually unaware that there was this api, when i searched for solutions just hundreds of "tutorials" on how to do it the way stated above were shown to me

Comment: Please [edit] your question to address comments (it is hard to read code in comments).  Looks like you are using a "free" embedded Google map.  Those aren't easily customizable in the way you want, to change things you need to use a (not free) API.

Comment: sorry it took me so long to respond. I wrote this after a long nightshift at 7 am pretty much the moment before going to sleep thus the weird wording and lack of structure. I've updated the post i hope that helps.
Basically i would prefer not paying for a ton of features that i actually dont need. All i want is to give people access to the normal google maps (or an alternative) so they can enter the location they are looking for on their own preferably without having to switch between pages constantly.

Comment: I might be able to use a "fake" or custom text input field and just check if the coordinates are right. Then swap an embedded map of the general area (which is there from the start) with another embedded map showing the correct location. I'm open to better suggestions though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the issues were solved by switching to open street maps. I can just use an iframe with a link to their website. It's not quite perfect yet but I may be able to customize it enough to work smoothly.

Answer (score 1):

As was noted in the comments this is probably not possible via the simple iframe embed.

However, if you use the Google Maps API, there is ample documentation for that found [here](https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox).

A quick example from the docs:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Places Search Box</title>
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #description {
        font-family: Roboto;
        font-size: 15px;
        font-weight: 300;
      }

      #infowindow-content .title {
        font-weight: bold;
      }

      #infowindow-content {
        display: none;
      }

      #map #infowindow-content {
        display: inline;
      }

      .pac-card {
        margin: 10px 10px 0 0;
        border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        outline: none;
        box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
        background-color: #fff;
        font-family: Roboto;
      }

      #pac-container {
        padding-bottom: 12px;
        margin-right: 12px;
      }

      .pac-controls {
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 5px 11px;
      }

      .pac-controls label {
        font-family: Roboto;
        font-size: 13px;
        font-weight: 300;
      }

      #pac-input {
        background-color: #fff;
        font-family: Roboto;
        font-size: 15px;
        font-weight: 300;
        margin-left: 12px;
        padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        width: 400px;
      }

      #pac-input:focus {
        border-color: #4d90fe;
      }

      #title {
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #4d90fe;
        font-size: 25px;
        font-weight: 500;
        padding: 6px 12px;
      }
      #target {
        width: 345px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search Box">
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      // This example adds a search box to a map, using the Google Place Autocomplete
      // feature. People can enter geographical searches. The search box will return a
      // pick list containing a mix of places and predicted search terms.

      // This example requires the Places library. Include the libraries=places
      // parameter when you first load the API. For example:
      // <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places">

      function initAutocomplete() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: -33.8688, lng: 151.2195},
          zoom: 13,
          mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
        });

        // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
        var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
        var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

        // Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.
        map.addListener('bounds_changed', function() {
          searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
        });

        var markers = [];
        // Listen for the event fired when the user selects a prediction and retrieve
        // more details for that place.
        searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
          var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

          if (places.length == 0) {
            return;
          }

          // Clear out the old markers.
          markers.forEach(function(marker) {
            marker.setMap(null);
          });
          markers = [];

          // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
          var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
          places.forEach(function(place) {
            if (!place.geometry) {
              console.log("Returned place contains no geometry");
              return;
            }
            var icon = {
              url: place.icon,
              size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
              origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
              anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
              scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
            };

            // Create a marker for each place.
            markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
              map: map,
              icon: icon,
              title: place.name,
              position: place.geometry.location
            }));

            if (place.geometry.viewport) {
              // Only geocodes have viewport.
              bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
            } else {
              bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
            }
          });
          map.fitBounds(bounds);
        });
      }

    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete"
         async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Also, I accidently revoked my flag but I noticed that this question could be closed as a duplicate of a number of questions, for example: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27826918/google-maps-embed-search-box), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29869261/google-map-search-box), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9850900/embed-google-map-with-search-bar).

Comment: Thanks, the solution was to replace Google maps with an iframe to open street maps.